# Background-Position not working At All [ CSS3 ]

Tags: css, sass

Tried to style `image` to fit my Screen, By using CSS3, but i think `background-repeat`, `background-position` or `background-size` not working at all..

Here the result that i archieved....

[image]

**`Code in Html`**

```
<v-card @click="addPos(item)" v-if="item.image" class="posCard">
    <div class="posCard--pos-img">
        <img :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/' + item.image" />
    </div>
    <div class="posCard--title">
        <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    </div>
</v-card>
```

**`And Here the code in style tag`**

```
<style lang="scss">
.posCard {
        border: #000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        // box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 1px rgba(60, 55, 68, 0.15);
        &--pos-img {
            height: 6rem;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: center;
        }

        &--title {
            text-align: center;
            background: #efefef;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Of course i thought, perhap i do something wrong in my Code....

Any Help will be appreciate. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Do you have any jsfiddle link with this issue?

Comment: `background-position` works when you set your image as a `background-image` in css not using `<img>`

Answer (score 1):

You are using image as a foreground and applying styles for background.

Try this.

```
<v-card @click="addPos(item)" v-if="item.image" class="posCard">
   <div class="posCard--pos-img">
   </div>
</v-card>

.posCard {
    &--pos-img {
        height: 6rem;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/item.image");
        background-position: center;
        background-size: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this class name "pos-img" in img tag and apply this style property and try

```
&--pos-img {
            height: 6rem;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: center;
        }
```